# LLVM libc++ not compiling with clang 3.3 on Mac OS

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, libc++

I have just downloaded clang 3.3 (homebrew) from the LLVM web page to my mac (OS X 10.8.4), but get this compiler error when using `std=c++11 stdlib=libc++`:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/v1/string:434:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/v1/algorithm:594:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/v1/memory:590:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/v1/typeinfo:61:
/usr/include/c++/v1/exception:146:5: error: an attribute list cannot appear here
    _LIBCPP_NORETURN friend void rethrow_exception(exception_ptr);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/v1/__config:190:28: note: expanded from macro '_LIBCPP_NORETURN'
#  define _LIBCPP_NORETURN [[noreturn]]
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

It seems that I also need another libc++ (even though it was said that it was 100% complete on MAC ...), but I cannot find any. Any help appreciated. Just for your info:

```
> clang++ -v
clang version 3.3 (tags/RELEASE_33/final)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

---

And, yes, I googled it and found this: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.compilers.llvm.bugs/24138 claiming it's resolved in libc++ trunk ???

---

Okay, as suggested by Howard, I've downloaded tip-of-the-trunk libc++ into /opt/local/share/libcxx, but have trouble building it. The manual says to `cd libcxx/lib`, `export TRIPLE=-apple-`, and run `./buildit`. I presume this implies `bash` (I'm usually a `tcsh` user, so I moved my `.tcshrc`, got a new shell and started `bash`). I did that and the compilations worked, but the library build failed. Apparently `./buildit` doesn't see `$TRIPLE=-apple-`, as it picks the wrong `LDSHARED_FLAG` (not that on line 81, but that on line 103, which is to be used if `$TRIPLE` is not set), even though `echo $TRIPLE` yields `-apple-` as it should. When I add the statement `echo TRIPLE = $TRIPLE` at the top of `buildit`, it reports nothing. How come? What is wrong here?

---

The failure was that because the wrong `LDSHARED_FLAG` was picked the loading didn't work (`ld` complaint about the unknown option `-soname` which, I think, makes sense under linux). I don't know why `buildit` (a `#! /bin/sh` file) didn't pick up the `TRIPLE` environment variable (it did pick up several unwanted ones such as `CXX` and `CC`). I now simply added `TRIPLE=-apple-` at the top of that file and it did built the library. However, the loader spitted out several warnings all of which were of the form

> ld: warning: direct access in ___cxa_bad_typeid to global weak symbol typeinfo for std::bad_typeid means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.

But most importantly, **it works** (the compilation at least, I have yet to test the library). I have one final question. The advice was to use `-I` and `-L` to tell the compiler about the whereabouts of this version. Is it not possible to put it into the usual place `/usr/include/c++/v1/`? Note that Xcode has its version somewhere else anyway and I had put in a symbolic link (`/usr/include/c++/v1/`) to that one to get my homebrew clang 3.2 working (after the some Xcode update). What about the library? Can I also put it in a standard place?

Comment: Any reason you're not using XCode 4.6.3 Command-Line Tools (Apple LLVM 4.2 and clang-425.0.28)? They are provided directly by Apple and easily installed via Xcode -> Preferences -> Download.

Comment: @sudopunk Yes: I want the latest version of clang (Apple LLVM 4.2 is llvm 3.1, but there is already 3.3).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the home page of libc++:

http://libcxx.llvm.org

You can download the tip-of-trunk libc++ from there.  You can tell clang to point to your download with `-nostdinc++ -I<path-to-libc++>/include`.  You can also tell clang to link to your tip-of-trunk libc++ with `-L<path-to-libc++>/lib` and `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=<path-to-libcxx>/lib`.  The directions are all on the libc++ home page.

Xcode is the easiest way to get clang + libc++.  But if you want the very latest, this is the place to go.

---

Congratulations!

Don't worry about the ld warning.  It is a harmless ld bug that will be fixed in a future release.  I see it on 10.8.4 too and it doesn't hurt anything.

The libc++ headers no longer live at `/usr/include/c++/v1`.  Xcode has migrated them into itself.  Having libc++ headers at `/usr/include/c++/v1` from older installs has been a source of confusion and bugs.  I regularly use `-nostdinc++ -I` to point to the libc++ headers I want (I often have several versions going at the same time), and that works well for me.

It is possible for you to replace your `/usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib` with that you have built.  I do not recommend doing this.  I **have** to sometimes to do a proper test, but I always do so very carefully because sometimes this causes me to have to reboot onto a backup disk and restore my `/usr/lib` to its original state.  If you do go this route, it is a very good idea to have a backup of the original `/usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib` very handy.

I recommend instead `-L` on the command line, and `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=<path-to-libcxx>/lib` in the shell.  More than one person (including myself) has gotten their computer into a really nasty place by not following this advice.

If you run `testit` (under `test/`), all you need is `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` in that shell.  The `testit` script is set up to point to the right places without an install.

Also I recommend figuring out why you had to modify `buildit`.  No one else is seeing that behavior.  `printenv` on your command line may help in this endeavor.

libc++ is updated often.  We try to keep tip-of-trunk always in a shippable state.

Comment: No.  But I do mean to say that I regularly run tip-of-trunk clang + tip-of-trunk libc++ on 10.8.4, and I'm willing to work with you until you achieve the same.

Comment: okay, so downloaded tip-of-the-trunk libc++, but building failed. If you can help me with that, this would be much appreciated, but these comments are not suitable. I'll edit the question instead.

Comment: Misspelled TRIPLE as TRIPPLE.

Comment: oops. no only in my question but not in the attempt. unfortunately.

Comment: Debug until `echo TRIPLE = $TRIPLE` confirms what you're trying to do.  Are you setting TRIPLE in one shell and running ./buildit in another?

Comment: What does the failure look like?

Comment: **Thanks for your help** (code compiles & runs)! I really think you should remove the bold claim (on the libc++ web page) that on MAC OS libc++ is a 100% complete implementation of C++11. It's just wrong and hence misleading.

Comment: Fair comment.  Although I do believe tip-of-trunk is a complete C++11 implementation.  And the latest Xcode contains a libc++ not too far from tip-of-trunk.  The error you pointed out did not occur with the clang that libc++ shipped with at the time.  It was just a simple bug exposed by finer error checking on a later clang, and was fixed 2012-11-28, nearly 9 months ago.  Xcode 5 (Developer Preview) currently ships with this bug fix.

Comment: *Although I do believe* -- better not rely on faith. Simple bugs such as this one are always possible, in particular if you only check with one compiler. Is libc++ actually used other than with clang? Is Xcode 5 available for mere mortals?

Comment: The bug free software is down the aisle next to the unicorns.  The libc++ homepage has links to developer mailing lists and archives so that you can find out who is doing what, and participate if you want.  Here's the link to Apple's developer site:  https://developer.apple.com